# Locate coordinate from angle from n nautical miles

Tags: c#, sql-server, math, geometry, geography

I am trying to find coordinate at D from a map.

The line from C to D needs to be at 90 degrees from Line A and B.

Coordinate D must be away from coordinate C from n nautical miles, coordinate C could be anywhere between the A and B.

I'm using C# using the namespace System.Data.Spatial to generate DbGeometry data.

The data which I'm working with like this  133043N1443814E TO 133515N1443710E THEN CLOCKWISE ON A 15.3 NM ARC CENTERED ON 133416N1445256E TO THE POINT OF ORIGIN

Other Sample of the data is at FAA website http://tfr.faa.gov/save_pages/detail_8_2189.html

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: Do you know any of the lengths for _AC_ or _BC_?  If you only know _n_ and that that _<ACD_ is 90 degrees, then I think you don't have enough information.   Can you please clarify what information you know (besides _n_).

Comment: You are kidding right?

Comment: I do know the coordinate AC and BC, i just need to know CD.
The data that i am workin with is please see revise.

Comment: squillman - C# with System.Data.Spatial to generate DbGeometry data.

Comment: Sean Lange 2 - I'm not kidding.  I'm parsing the data from FAA Temporary Flight Restriction website http://tfr.faa.gov/save_pages/detail_8_2189.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Example with mutliple coordinates before creating an arc. AREA DEFINED AS 133830N1450807E TO 132836N1444449E TO 133043N1443814E TO 133515N1443710E THEN CLOCKWISE ON A 15.3 NM ARC CENTERED ON 133416N1445256E TO THE POINT OF ORIGIN
                    //Abbreviation
                    //    a
                    //    b
                    //    m(midangle)   (cx,cy,ax,ay,bx,by)
                    //    x(lat)
                    //    y(long)
                    //Xc=latitude provided in text for center point
                    //Yc=longitude provided in text for center point

                    //point is the last point
                    var startPointStr = generateCircleLine[generateCircleLine.Length - 1].Split(' ');

                    var startPoint = new TfrXY { LngX = Convert.ToDouble(startPointStr[0]), LatY = Convert.ToDouble(startPointStr[1]) };
                    //point before the last point

                    var stopPointStr = generateCircleLine[generateCircleLine.Length - 2].Split(' ');

                    var stopPoint = new TfrXY { LngX = Convert.ToDouble(stopPointStr[0]), LatY = Convert.ToDouble(stopPointStr[1]) };
                    var centerPoint = new TfrXY { LngX = Convert.ToDouble(centerPointStr[0]), LatY = Convert.ToDouble(centerPointStr[1]) };

                    var a = Math.Atan2(stopPoint.LatY- centerPoint.LatY, stopPoint.LngX-centerPoint.LngX);
                    var b = Math.Atan2(startPoint.LatY-centerPoint.LatY, startPoint.LngX-centerPoint.LngX);

                    var m = MidAngle(centerPoint.LngX, centerPoint.LatY, startPoint.LngX, startPoint.LatY, stopPoint.LngX, stopPoint.LatY);

                    var d = Math.Sqrt(      
                        Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(centerPointStr[0]) - startPoint.LngX, 2) +
                        Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(centerPointStr[1]) - startPoint.LatY, 2)   );

                    var ym = (centerPoint.LatY) +( d * Math.Sin(m));
                    var xm = (centerPoint.LngX) + (d * Math.Cos(m));








The latidude and longitude would be  ym  and xml

You will also need to use this function.



        /// <summary>
        /// Find mid angle
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cx">center point longitude</param>
        /// <param name="cy">center point latitude</param>
        /// <param name="ax">Starting point longitude </param>
        /// <param name="ay">Starting point latitude</param>
        /// <param name="bx">Stopping point longitude</param>
        /// <param name="by">Stopping point latitude</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static double MidAngle(double cx, double cy, double ax, double ay, double bx, double by)
        {

            var a = Math.Atan2(ay - cy, ax - cx);
            var b = Math.Atan2(by - cy, bx - cy);

            //Fixing infinite loop issue
            if ((ax == cx) && (ay > cy))
                a = Math.PI / 2.0;
            else if ((ax == cx) && (ay <= cy))
                a = -Math.PI / 2.0;
            else
                a = Math.Atan2(ay - cy, ax - cx);

            if ((bx == cx) && (by > cy))
                b = Math.PI / 2.0;
            else if ((bx == cx) && (by <= cy))
                b = -Math.PI / 2.0;
            else
                b = Math.Atan2(by - cy, bx - cx);



            var delta = a - b;
            while (delta < 0)
            {
                delta += 2 * Math.PI;
            }
            return a - (delta / 2);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

One could for example proceed as follows:

1. find the course (azimuth) between points `A` and `B` using this [formula](http://www.edwilliams.org/avform.htm#Crs)
2. find the mid-point of the section of the great circle connecting `A` and `B` via this [formula](http://www.edwilliams.org/avform.htm#Intermediate) (with `f=0.5` for the mid-point)
3. by fixing the point obtained in previous step and adjusting the azimuth obtained in the first step (subtracting pi/2 modulo 2*pi), one can [calculate](http://www.edwilliams.org/avform.htm#LL) the required point D for a prescribed distance

If the point `C` is specified in advance, one can skip step 2 and use this point directly in step 3 together with the adjusted course calculated in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the calculation you need prior to adding the sql tag to your question. You're not quite ready for sql server help, you need logic help first, and then math help.

You have marked the location of C to be 1/2 way on your illustration, however 90 degrees from line AB could be higher or lower on the line than directly in the middle. There is also no mention of it stated in your question, after you define all of the requirements then on to math help.

Once you have the equation, then show the code you plan on using in SQL Server or C# and where you plan on doing the 'heavy lifting' of the code first. Then the communities can assist.

I do think it is a very interesting question and will get attention.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18683029)

Comment: Thank you for the link, reading through it, you would find that this answer is a full and valid answer. 'Generally, truly important information should be incorporated into an answer anyway (either by posting a new answer, if the information answers the question at least partially...' but I'll edit my answer to remove the comment about commenting